# improve this Clojure code to get more idiomatic

Tags: performance, clojure

Any way I can get more idiomatic Clojure with the following code. I know I'm missing something regarding destructuring. At least I can say that I understand the current code. My first temptation was to use `doseq` and then populate a `hash-map`, but I was sure that `map` was the solution.

The code reads a CSV file -

```
Name,Department,Score
Rohan,IT,8
Bob,Sales,6
Tom,IT,9
Jane,Accounting,3
Mary,Sales,9
Harry,IT,8
Frodo,Marketing,8
Bilbo,Accounting,10
```

and will output rows sorted by highest score. Simple!

```
(def file "scores.csv")

(defn list-of-vecs []
  (let [file-str (slurp file)]
    (let [lines (clojure.string/split-lines file-str)]
      (next (map #(clojure.string/split % #",") lines)))))

(defn list-of-maps []
    (map (fn [n] {:name (n 0), :department (n 1), :score (Integer/parseInt (n 2))})
        (list-of-vecs)))

(defn sorted-list []
  (reverse (sort-by :score (list-of-maps))))

(defn print-high-scores []
  (prn "Name","Department","Score")
  (map (fn [m] (prn (m :name) (m :department) (m :score))) (sorted-list)))
```

Any feedback would be appreciated, including on indentation.

Also I was very surprised by the performance (running inside lein).

CSV file of **8 lines**

```
parse-csv.core=> (time print-high-scores)
 "Elapsed time: 0.026059 msecs"
```

CSV file of **25k lines**

```
parse-csv.core=> (time print-high-scores)
"Elapsed time: 0.025636 msecs"
```

Comment: Or am I using `time` incorrectly?

Comment: A more practical and reliable way would be using a library for CSV parsing. Blindly splitting by commas will fail if a (quoted) value turns out to have a comma inside. Is that viable in your case? And I think this question belongs more to CodeReview.SE. You're not solving a problem really, you're looking for ways to improve your code.

Comment: Clojure has an official CSV reader: https://github.com/clojure/data.csv  Then do 1: parse the integer with a simple `map`. 2: `sort-by`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(time (print-high-scores))`?

Comment: I think this question is a better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I know. I have never heard of code review SE before. Thats the reason I upvoted @D-side :)

Comment: @Sylwester That would be more correct but will still take zero time, because `print-high-scores` is lazy, immediately returning a lazy sequence and only printing anything when that sequence is realized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does your `(time print-high-scores)` actually print anything ?

`Or am I using time incorrectly`:

I think you are useing it correctly but measuring the wrong thing.

my approach:

```
; read file - drop header line
(def input 
  (rest (line-seq (clojure.java.io/reader "inputfilename"))))

; top ten
(def top-ten 
  (take 10 (time (sort-by 
              #(- (Integer/parseInt (nth % 2))) ; negate so highest first
              (map (fn [line] 
                     (clojure.string/split line #",")) input)))))
; 10 lines  "Elapsed time:  0.469539 msecs"
; 25k lines "Elapsed time: 68.157863 msecs"

; print - sideeffect
(time (doseq [e (doall top-ten)] 
  (print e "\n")))

"Elapsed time: 0.02804 msecs"
[Bilbo Accounting 10]
[Tom IT 9]
[Mary Sales 9]
[Rohan IT 8]
[Harry IT 8]
[Frodo Marketing 8]
[Bob Sales 6]
[Jane Accounting 3]
nil
```